# Why my "<div * ngIf" erases my items from my <li>

Tags: angular

I currently have a problem that I have never had.

With this code below my texts appear correctly.

[image]

```
<li data-help="4">
<span class="numberIconPage2" style="position: absolute; top: -238px">4</span>
    <p class="titrePage2" style="position: absolute; top: -238px;">
        {{'1609-1611' | t }}
   </p>
   <p class="step1 help-1" >
      <input type="text" class="inputSignInAccess" [(ngModel)]="otp">
                  
   </p>
</li>
```

When I add this condition

```
<div *ngIf="otp.length > 2 ">
    Max 2 characters long.
</div>
```

My texts have disappeared.

[image]

However, if I enter a figure in the input, the elements appear correctly.

[image]

I would like the text to display even if the user does not enter any value.

I don't understand why the condition is confusing my HTML code?

```
<li data-help="4">
 <span class="numberIconPage2" style="position: absolute; top: -238px">4</span>
    <p class="titlePage2" style="position: absolute; top: -238px;">
         {{'1609-1611' | t }}
    </p>
     
    <input type="text" class="inputSignInAccess" [(ngModel)]="otp">
       <div *ngIf="otp.length > 2 ">
          Max 2 characters long.
       </div> 
       
</li>
```

Thank you very much for your answer.

Comment: could you share your code at a `ngFor` level please?

Comment: Check the dev tools console for errors

Comment: please create a running version of your problem at stackblitz or somewhere else so that we will be able to see the problem and solve it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My guess is `otp` is undefined (or possibly null), you are getting "Cannot read property *length* of undefined" in the console, and this error messes up rendering the template. The fix would be `*ngIf="otp?.length > 2"`, or initializing `otp` to an empty string.

Was I right?

Comment: Thank you very much it works perfectly! How do you initialize the variable `opt` in HTML ?? I do not understand?

Comment: @elodie not in HTML, in the TS. I'm assuming `opt` is declared there, `opt: string` or similar. Just make it `opt: string = ''`, or simply `opt = ''`.